# A game with a die and a watch

Tags: probability

You have a broken watch with the hour hand pointing initially at 12.
You start throwing a die and for each outcome $x=\{1,\dots,6\}$ you move the hour hand $x$ hours forward.
After 2008 tosses, what is the probability of having the hour hand laying horizontally (i.e. pointing 3 or 9)?

Intuitively I'm quite sure the answer should be 1/6, but I'm not able to get the result rigorously.

The problem could be generalized as follows: given a $k$-sided die, what is the probability that the sum of $n$ tosses is congruent to $a$ mod $b$?

Comment: Are you familiar with transition matrices?

Comment: Try computing the conditional probability of ending up horizontally after 2008 tosses, _assuming that_ the position after 2007 tosses is 1. Then assuming the position after 2007 tosses is 2, then 3, then 4 ...

Comment: @Paul No sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_{n}$ be the number that the hour hand points to after $n$ rolls, $X_{n}\in \{1,2, \dotsc , 12\}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
P(X_{2018}=3,9)&=\sum_{k=1}^{12}P(X_{2018}=3,9\mid X_{2017}=k)P(X_{2017}=k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{12}\frac{1}{6}P(X_{2017}=k)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^{12}P(X_{2017}=k)=\frac{1}{6}
\end{align}
$$
by the law of total probability.

Comment: OK that's perfect thanks

Answer (score 4):

After 2007 tosses, the hour hand is pointing in some direction. That is, if we denote the hour by $h$, then $h\equiv \ k \ (mod \ 12)$ for some $k$ (here 0 corresponds to 12 on the clock). Then we roll the die one last time, meaning each of the outcomes $h+1,h+2,h+3,h+4,h+5,h+6$ (taken mod 12) are all equally likely. Since precisely one of 3 or 9 must appear in this list, the probability is indeed 1/6.

Comment: OK but the process should be iterated, shouldn't it? I mean, you are assuming that every $h$ has the same probability...

Answer (score 2):

Prove by induction that the hour hand's value modulo $6$ is equally likely to be any of $0\dots5$ after $n$ trials.  This is obvious when $n=1$ and it's easy to go from $n$ to $n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the magic numbers $6$ sides on the die and $12$ hours on the clock, the answer is exactly $\frac 16$.  Wherever you are after the $2007^{th}$ roll there is exactly one roll that will leave the hand horizontal.

If you were using a $d5$ the problem would not be as simple.  The probability would be *very* close to $\frac 16$, but not be it exactly.  It can't be exact because there are $5^{2008}$ sequences of rolls, which is not divisible by $6$.  To compute it you can form a coupled set of recurrences.  It helps to define the hand positions $\bmod 6$, so they range from $0$ to $5$.  Then let $p(a,n)$ be the chance that the hand points at $a$ after $n$ rolls.  You have $$p(a,n)=\frac 15(p(a-1,n-1)+p(a-2,n-1)+p(a-3,n-1)+p(a-4,n-1)+p(a-5,n-1))\\ p(0,0)=1$$.  Where the subtraction in the first argument is $\bmod 6$  The probabilities will approach $\frac 16$ quickly.